# Forms not able to be edited on chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

I have a form that works in all browsers except chrome, for some reason chrome won't let me click in and type in the form fields, here is the form:

```
    <form action="registration.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <p style="color:red; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;"> <?php echo $errorMsg; ?> </p>
        <label style="margin-bottom:10px" for="username">Username</label>
        <input style="margin-bottom:10px"name="username" id="username" value="<?php print $username; ?>" type="text" />
        <label style="margin-bottom:10px" for="email">Email</label>
        <input style="margin-bottom:10px" name="email" id="email" value="<?php print $email; ?>" type="text" />
        <label style="margin-bottom:10px" for="emailconf">Confirm Email</label>
        <input style="margin-bottom:10px" name="emailconf" id="emailconf" value="<?php print $emailconf; ?>" type="text" />
        <label style="margin-bottom:10px" for="paypal">PayPal Email</label>
        <input style="margin-bottom:10px" name="paypal" id="paypal" value="<?php print $paypal; ?>" type="text" />
        <label style="margin-bottom:10px" for="pass">Password</label>
        <input style="margin-bottom:10px" type="password" value="<?php print $pass; ?>" name="pass" id="pass" onkeyup="passwordStrength(this.value)" />
        <label style="margin-bottom:10px" for="passwordconf">Confirm Password</label>
         <input style="margin-bottom:10px" name="passwordconf" id="passwordconf" value="<?php print $passwordconf; ?>" type="password" />
           <div style="height:35; color:black;" id="passwordDescription">Password not entered</div>
           <div id="passwordStrength" class="strength0"></div>
    </fieldset>
        <input style="float:right; margin-right:45%;" id="SaveAccount" type="submit" class="loginbtn" value="Submit Form"/>
    </form>
```

The php print is so if there are errors they don't have to retype the information again, and as far as I can tell can be ignored. Is there any reason as to why chrome would behave this way? I'm by no means a form master, but I have made some in the past the same way and they worked before if memory serves.

Comment: That's not enough code for us to solve your problem. The code you gave will work. Something else is causing the problem. Please make a testcase the reproduces the problem on http://jsfiddle.com

Comment: ok, I'll put the entire form here, if you need the php then let me know.

Comment: can you put up the html which is produced by your php.  I.e. the source code of the page in the browser.

Comment: It is a lot of code, maybe it will be easier for people to view the source code: http://graphic-shack.com/registration.php

When I have it functional I'll be relocating the css and so on to external files, for now it is all there.

Comment: your left and right divs are covering the form, if you remove these you will find you are able to click the form.

Comment: ah ok, they have to be there to center everything, would setting a z-index fix that?

Comment: why cant you position it a different way? I can't say Ive ever had a positioning div covering any of my content.

Comment: The center div is fixed while the left and right divs are fluid, creating two divs at 50% width with fixed negative margins is the only way I've figured out how to do that.

Comment: just put 'margin: 0 auto;' on your center div and forget about the left and right ones...

Comment: dev-null-dweller was spot on with the positioning for a quick fix, but thanks for pointing out the actual issue, it's really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix: add `position:relative` to `#main_wrapper`

Proper fix: Whole layout needs <s>many changes...</s> redesign (`table` with whole row full of `nbsp`? seriously? )

Comment: Worked perfect, and yeah it isn't ideal but it'll have to do until I find a new way to achieve the same thing. Cheers.

Comment: For the record I never permanently develop with tables, it is a quick sampler, I'll follow up with divs now that look and function are what I want, saves me a bit of time, rather than making it with divs and saying 'nah i dont like that' and then having to do it all again.